# StackDriver Custom Metric Resource Type cloud_composer_environment

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-composer

I have a problem when I create timeseries on StackDriver.

So basically I create time series by executing the API from this site https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.timeSeries/create

and for the resource type I set it as `cloud_composer_environment'.

and the JSON looks like

```
"resource": {
        "type": "cloud_composer_environment",
        "labels": {
          "project_id": "MY PROJECT ID",
          "environment_name": "MY ENVIRONTMENT",
          "location": "us-central1"
        }
      },
```

and when I execute the API, the result was

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "One or more TimeSeries could not be written: Metrics cannot be written to cloud_composer_environment.: timeSeries[0]",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

and I dont know How to fix it, there is no information why was it a bad request

Answer (score 2):

Composer stackdriver metrics are not publicly writable today and we are currently working on exposing more workflow-related metrics. Meanwhile, you may want to [create your own metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics) for reporting and/or use composer stackdriver logs for monitoring/alerting as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/monitoring-environments).

Comment: Hi @Feng Lu, how can I know the composer stackdriver not publicly writeable, is there any page has the list of Resource Type that not writeable?

look at from this, https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/resources , there is no information that the resource type is not writeable